# Copiar conteúdo de uma pasta com todas as subpastas e arquivos pra dentro de uma nova

Tags: c#

Estou tendo dificuldades de criar uma pasta dentro de outra e mover o conteúdo para dentro dessa nova pasta. A regra é a seguinte:

1. Eu descompacto um arquivo `.zip` dentro desse diretório:`C:\Teste_Zip\Destino_Teste\Temp/>`. Bem se existir a pasta `web`, aí começa o meu negócio.
2. Dentro da pasta `web`, devo criar duas pastas: `FarmInterna` e `FarmExterna`. Tudo que tiver dentro da pasta `web`, deve ser movido para a pasta `FarmInterna` e a nova pasta `FarmExterna` serão copiados alguns arquivos, baseado em uma outra regra.

Bem, a questão toda é que ao criar a nova pasta, não consigo mover os arquivos e a pasta é deletada e não sei porque.

Veja o meu código:

```
private void CriaPastaFarmInterna()
{
    string path_trabalho = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Target_Dir_Temp"];
    string novo_path = path_trabalho + "\\FarmInterna";

    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(novo_path);

    if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(novo_path);

        List<String> myFiles = Directory
                               .GetFiles(path_trabalho, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        foreach (string file in myFiles)
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
                // to remove name collusion
            if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
            mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
        }            
    }
```

A necessidade e criar e mover para a `FarmInterna`.

Melhorando a pergunta, a pasta `FarInterna` deve estar dentro da pasta web e as pastas e arquivos que deverão ser movidos para essa pasta, são somente as pastas e arquivos que estiverem dentro da pasta web, exceto a pasta `FarmInterna`, é óbvio.

Refiz meu código e quando chega no foreach, ao dá um `moveTo()`, ele diz que não foi possível achar parte do caminho. Ou seja, ele entra com o path correto, mas como a pasta FarmInterna está vazia, deve ser isso, não existe a pasta. Abaixo o novo código.

```
private void CriaPastaFarmInterna()
{
    string path_trabalho = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Target_Dir_Temp"] + @"\web";
    string novo_path = path_trabalho + @"\FarmInterna";

    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(novo_path);

    if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(novo_path);

        List<String> myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path_trabalho, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        List<String> myDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(path_trabalho).ToList();

        var diretorios = myDirectories.Where(d => !d.Contains("FarmInterna"));

        foreach (var di in diretorios)
        { 
            foreach (string file in myFiles)
            {
                FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
                string newFile = novo_path + (file.Replace(path_trabalho, ""));
                    //string newFile = novo_path + "\\" + (file.Replace(path_trabalho, ""));

                if (new FileInfo(newFile).Exists == false)
                    mFile.MoveTo(newFile);
                }
            }    
        }
```

Comment: Não há nada no seu código que faria a pasta 'FarmInterna' ser excluída. Porém, há algumas incoerências no seu código: 1. O método `GetFiles` lista somente arquivos e não diretórios. Para listar tudo da pasta, seria necessário utilizar também o método `GetDirectories`. 2. Ao listar diretórios também, sua pasta `FarmInterna` entraria na lista do que deve ser copiado - você deveria adicionar uma verificação para que ela não seja movida também.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius, a minha dúvida está no seguinte. A pasta FarmInterna deveria estar dentro da pasta web e quando eu faço isso, me dá a mensangem que já está sendo utilizada e não faz nada mais.

Answer (score -1):

```
  public void copiaDiretorio(string input,string output)
    {


        if (!Directory.Exists(output)) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(output);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(input);
            foreach (string arquivo in arquivos)
            {
                File.Copy(input + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(arquivo), output + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(arquivo));
            }
            string[] diretorios = Directory.GetDirectories(input);
            foreach (string diretorio in diretorios)
            {
                copiaDiretorio(diretorio, output + @"\" + diretorio.Split(Convert.ToChar(@"\"))[diretorio.Split(Convert.ToChar(@"\")).Length - 1]);
            }
        }

    }
```